# Make a list distinct list of a list

Tags: c#, list

I have a C# List of sting which can be x rows long. a small example will be shown below. I would like to know how i would to now how i can get small distinct list so that `A` doesn't appear multiple time.  this list is coming for code. so it random.

```
list = {a,b,a,f,a,null,a,e,a,e}
```

Comment: What about other characters such as `e`? Do you want it to be unique too?

Comment: Also, is `a` the same as `A`? You mentiond uppercase A in the text but your list contains lowercase a. Mentioned a way to ignore the case in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18355752/284240). Btw, with `Distinct` it works the same way: `Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try LINQ ....
To be more specific...
Given that your list is actually string[] you could do this...

```
string[] list = {"a","b","a","f","a",null,"a","e","a","e"};
var distinctList = list.Distinct();

foreach (var str in distinctList)//Distinct list of values
{
    Console.Write(str); 
}
```

Comment: _"list is actually string[]"_ It does not need to be an array, `Distinct` works with all types of `IEnumerable<T>`. Apart from that, since `Enumerable.Distinct` is implemented using deferred execution it is actually not a `distinctList`. It is just the query which gets executed at a `foreach` or other methods that materialize it(f.e. `ToList`). So you should mention that since OP wants to have a "distinct **list**" . Otherwise you will always execute this query which is inefficient if the values don't change anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(list);
```

If you want to replace your old list with the unique list:

```
list = set.ToList();
```

`HashSet<T>` has many [useful and efficient methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383091.aspx) which are often overlooked.

> The `HashSet<T>` class provides high-performance set operations. A set
>   is a collection that **contains no duplicate elements**, and whose
>   elements are in no particular order.

**Update** *"so that `A` doesn't appear multiple time"*

Since the list contains lower case `a` i assume that you don't know that .NET compares case-sensitive by default. You could compare case insensitive in this way:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(list, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the distinct() keyword like this:

```
List<string> foo = new List<string> {"a","b","a","f", "a", null,"a" ,"e","a","e"};
foreach (var element in foo.Distinct())
{
    element.Dump();
}
```

Output:

```
a
b
f
null 
e
```

This is written in Linqpad. The Dump method will not be available to you